# React native: Module `DrawerLayoutAndroid` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error while my app is being installed on my device/emulator:

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module
>   `DrawerLayoutAndroid` from
>   `/Users/anandchandran/Desktop/cognito-RN/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`
>
> : Module `DrawerLayoutAndroid` does not exist in the Haste module map

Answer (score 1):

running `npm link` fixed the issue for me

[Documentation found here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the 'DrawerLayoutAndroid' from "/Users/anandchandran/Desktop/cognito-RN/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js"

It works fine now..
If you are still getting some errors delete the node modules and reinstall and link it.