# React Native Error: Module `ProgressBarAndroid` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I created a React Native project on Windows 10 using create-react-native-app. Then I ran npm run eject to get a standard React Native application. For a few days, the application was working fine, running npm run android would display the application on my device correctlu. But after installing a few modules (react-native-app-auth, react-native-navigation), this error started popping up in the Node console whenever I tried to run the application, and is now constantly popping up in every project, even the new ones.

```
path\to\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `ProgressBarAndroid` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at C:\path\to\project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:473
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

I tried following the instructions there, to no avail: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

I also tried following the instructions there (my issue doesn't seem related to theirs), to no avail: [React native: Module `DrawerLayoutAndroid` does not exist in the Haste module map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863961/react-native-module-drawerlayoutandroid-does-not-exist-in-the-haste-module-ma)
If I do what is suggested in the only reply, then the same error appears but with a different native module, and if I keep removing the lines, it keeps popping up with a different module every time.

I also tried starting from scratch, creating a new project, using different versions of react-native, even reinstalling Node and npm entirely, but the error still pops up. The only way I found to make it work again is to start from scratch on another machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have the same issue, could you resolve it?

Comment: Nope... The workaround I found was to remove the native modules from the implementation JS file, which means that for the moment, my React Native app cannot use the modules ProgressBarAndroid, DatePickerAndroid and TouchableNativeFeedback. I also had to comment out some sections of several React Native JS files.
Even though TouchableNativeFeedback is a part of the Button class, buttons still seem to function normally.